# File write permission to application directory in windows 7 in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I am creating an AIR application using Flex. In it I use a file in application directory to store some data in it.Its working very well to read and write data to this file with various OS except windows 7. In windows 7 it is not working. May be its a permission problem.

How can i write file in the application directory with Windows 7 ?

Thanks
Arif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the user directory instead of the application directory to store data?

Instead of [applicationDirectory](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory) use [applicationStorageDirctory](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationStorageDirectory).  Your app should always have access to write tot he latter.

Answer (score 1):

Is User Account Control active on the system? Air may not be triggering a UAC prompt properly, but if it is on, depending on the access restrictions, you will need to have the user ok any changes to the Program Files folder(s).

**Edit**

Turns out you never have the ability to write to the path associated with File.applicationDirectory, at least as far as the documentation is concerned.